# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare (PHP/Apache Setup)

Tags: apache2, php

I am running an Apache2/PHP5 web server on my Mac (Mountain Lion). When I upgraded from Lion to Mountain Lion, I lost my dev environment/configs. Whilst trying to set everything up, I have somehow borked my httpd or php.ini configuration (I think, anyway)... when I point my browser to my localhost, I get the infamous PHP error:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare (some random function).

Regardless of the page I point it to, I get this. Prior to the loss of my web server settings, this was not happening, so I am confident that the files are okay and all syntax is good (the whole site consistently uses include_once and require_once also).

I think it has to do with my virtual host setup or working directory setup... I've tried a number of things, but no joy so far.

I am happy to provide any/all info that would be useful... I'm at my wit's end on this. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` file. Does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case, it happened to be a bad vhosts setup. Once I fixed a kind of redirect issue there, it solved the problem.

Both of the other answers (and comments) supplied here are VERY good though, and should help anyone with similar issues in the future debug their code. Very rarely will you goof up like I did with vhosts and run into this problem (but not a ton of others). Big thank you to Ross Smith II, metal_fan and Jeffrey for their help in this!

Answer (score 2):

You've most likely changed your `include_path` so you are loading the same php file using different paths. When you do this, php can't tell it's the same file, so it loads the file a second time, which causes the `Cannot redeclare` error.

One way to track down the problem is to add the following right before the offending line:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path()));
print_r(get_included_files());
```

Answer (score 1):

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare (some random function)/class

Always Means that the function or class with the SAME name has been defined before,
Take a look at this example:

```
<?php


function test(){
 return 1;
}

function test(){
 return 2;
}
//will produce fatal error like yours


class A {}
class A {}
//Will say that it can't redeclare class A
```

Here's the clue you should start from
Make sure that:, your include path is set accordingly

To get some clue, try:

```
<?php

print_r ( get_included_files() );

?>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the case, but the problem is not in it's project, it's in apache. You just gave a clue of what the error is about, you are not providing an answer to solve it.

Comment: But - it says `PHP : Fatal error cannot redeclare ...` So what do we have? 1) This file (contained function/class) has been included before and user includes this one again, via include() not include_once() 2) get_included_files() will help to DETERMINE if that file is that need to be included

Comment: The author should give more informations, I agree with you on that. But it's not the author's fault for this error. It's probably some Apache class that is included 2 times and run two times. So the best suggestion you could give is to do a new clean install of the server and clean the apache file folder. Running `get_included_files()` will give him the files that HE included, not Apache.

Comment: The new and clean installation might be dirty work - this is very very general advice. Everything depends on skills / server etc etc. I got that the problem is in `include_path`- I've mentioned that in my answer too

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed that problem looking in another forum.
In my case, te problem was that:
`<?php
include "file.inc";
$user = new user()
....
?>`
`<?php
include "file.inc"
....
?>`
I included two times "file.inc", and that was the problem. Juust keep the include in the "main" file and that's all!